# ADODB.Connection.Execute return value / execute validation

Tags: validation, vb6, oracle10g, ado, oraoledb

When using the `ADODB.Connection.Execute` command, if the query returns a recordset, the `ADODB.Recordset` object can be checked for validity to confirm if the query/command was executed successfully.

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

If a command that updates rows but does not return records is executed, the `ADODB.Connection.Execute` command writes to the optional `RecordsAffected` variable. Is a count of the records affected and can be used to confirm if the query/command was executed successfully.

**Example:**

```
UPDATE users SET active = '0' WHERE...
```

How would you confirm if the query/command was executed successfully in the following example, or any situation where you are issuing a command that doesn't return records and no records are being affected?

**Example:**

```
SAVEPOINT FIRST_SAVEPOINT
```

Note: I am using OraOLEDB as my provider for the connection string.

Comment: With SQL Server, you can return @@RowCount to return the number of rows affected by a query.  Perhaps Oracle has something similar.

Comment: It's possible with Oracle too, but my question is related to commands that wouldn't update or return rows.

Comment: If an error occurs when that command is executed, it should bubble up to the calling code which should raise an error in the VB6 code. If there is no error and no rows affected, would it be safe to assume that it executed successfully?

Comment: @jakdep I was hoping to evaluate the recordset in some shape or form to achieve this, but trapping the error this way seems the best way to go.